# Prove that a cone C is full-dimensional if and only if its dual cone $C^*$ is pointed.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, convex-cone, dual-cone

> A cone with apex $0$ is said to be pointed if it does not contain any non-trivial subspace. Let C be a closed convex cone with apex $0$. Show that $C$ is full-dimensional if and only if its dual cone $C^*$ is pointed.

I'm doing the forward direction of the proof and need some help. Here's my attempt.

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.
Assume $S^*$ is a non-trivial subspace of $C^*$. Then for all $z \in S^*$, we have $-z \in S^*$. Since both $z$ and $-z$ are in $C^*$, for all $x \in C$, we have $\langle x,z\rangle  \geq 0$ and $\langle x,-z\rangle  \geq 0$. So $\langle x,z\rangle = 0$ (1).

It's here that I got stuck. I think I need to either show that, if $x$ is written as $x = \lambda_1i_1 + \dotsb + \lambda_di_d$, where $i_1,...,i_d$ are unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then by (1), $\lambda_1z_1 + ... + \lambda_dz_d = 0$, and somehow deduce that at least one of the $\lambda_i = 0$. Or I need to prove my suspection that $S^*$ is not full-dimensional. Both cases would lead to the contradiction that $C$ is not full-dimensional.

Comment: Why does Wikipedia define pointedness as containing the origin? What user533068 defines as *pointed* is what Wikipedia refers to as flat. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: Now you know that $C$ is contained in the hyperplane $\langle y,z\rangle=0$ (here, $z$ is fixed and $y$ is a variable).  Since a hyperplane is of lower dimension than the ambient space, it follows that $C$ is not full dimensional.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't done this for a while so I'm a bit fuzzy on the details. What is it about a space X that makes it a hyperplane (i.e. not full-dimensional), if for all $x \in X$ and for a vector $z$, $<x,z> = 0$? I can see the argument holds for the plane and the 3-dim space, just don't know why it's true in general.

Comment: It's easiest if I "cheat" and not worry about the difference between dual vectors and vectors.  In this case, $y$ satisfies a linear equation, namely $\langle y,z\rangle=0$ (the coefficients are the entries of $z$).  This space consists of all vectors which are perpendicular to $z$.  If you take a basis of the vectors perpendicular to $z$, you'll get one fewer than the dimension of the ambient space.

Comment: Could you also check the following proof for the reverse direction? I'd like to apply the same idea to prove the contrapositive: if C is not full-dimensional, then $C^*$ is not pointed. Proof: since C is not full-dimensional, there exists a line in $R^d$ such that every point on this line is a vector perpendicular to all vectors in C. Clearly this line is in $C^*$, and it's also a non-trivial subspace of $C^*$. So $C^*$ is not pointed.